# coldfusion sessions dropped when initiated by a different domain

Tags: session, coldfusion, dns, session-cookies

I've got a login page that's on one domain, and the application on another.

When I use the login from the separate domain, the session variables are not stored for the second domain, even though that is the domain that creates them.

To be clear, I'm not sharing sessions between the domains

login domain runs a script on the app domain, where the app creates a session variable.
This variable is not being transferred when a redirect is called within the app domain.

If I call the script from the same domain, the session is stored as expected. Funny enough, this was working fine up until today. Some cf setting changed perhaps.

I've noticed that the CFID and CFTOKEN are being passed, is it possible that the session is written using the CFID and CFTOKEN from the referring website?

if so how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may override default session cookie behaviour by setting `this.setclientcookies = false` in Application.cfc, and issue your cfcookie's in Application.cfc's `onSessionStart()`

e.g.

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cfset this.sessionmanagement = true>
  <cfset this.setclientcookies = false>
  <cffunction name="onSessionStart">
      <cfcookie name="CFID" value="#session.cfid#" domain=".subdomain.domain.com">
      <cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="#session.cftoken#" domain=".subdomain.domain.com">
  </cffunction>
<cfcomponent>
```

While you're at it, it'd be a good idea to set the `httpOnly` attribute to true as well.

Comment: I get an error `Routines cannot be declared more than once.` when I include the cffunction bit. and `<cfset this.sessionmanagement = true>
  <cfset this.setclientcookies = false>` hasn't worked for me :(

Comment: Do you `onSessionStart` declared somewhere else in the App.cfc file, that's what that error sounds like.

Comment: I'm using CFwheels, so yes there is that :). I added it to the right place but it still wasn't working.

Comment: @Daniel make sure you don't pass CFID/CFTOKEN on cflocation.

Comment: can you elaborate? why not?

Comment: @Daniel It may mess up your session.  If your cookies is set to use session#A, and the URL is somehow set to use session#B, CF server will process the request as session#B no matter what session data is in your cookie.